# Visual Studio QT project MainForm.ui expected a declaration

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2019, qt-vs-addin

I have a project in QT Creator and am trying to import it into Visual Studio 2019.  I have solved all the issues except there is an error E0169 expected a declaration in mainwindow.ui.  The problem with this error is that there is no highlighting of where the error is. I tried right clicking and compiling the mainwindow.ui file and it works and produces the ui_mainwindow.h as well as copying the compiled code directly from QT Designer into the ui_mainwindow.h...

The specific error is pointing to the mainwindow.ui. When I double click it, QTDesigner is opened so that is not helpful.(I have looked at it in XML editor and cannot see an issue) I do not understand what is going on as mainwindow.ui is just an xml file so how can the compiler have issues with it.  I do not believe it is a problem with the code, I believe its a setting in VS....

Anyone else having an issue like this?  Let me know if there is any settings or code that would help diagnose this.

Steps so far...
Installed QT tools
Imported the project
Re-targeted solution to 10.xxxxx

Thanks

Comment: I don't use the vs tools addon however I believe it's trying to compile the .ui file as `c++` code. I changed a few tags in the hope of attracting users who use the VS addon.

Comment: Strange thing is, even if I exclude it from project, error still persists...

Comment: I found the issue. VS did not like the first line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. Removed it and got the project working after a few other small issues.

Comment: I don't think that is the correct solution. I have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` on every one of my hundreds (yes 100s) of `.ui` files however I am using `CMake` instead of the `VS Addon`. I think the solution you mention may prevent uic from working.